# Transferring video off the phone from isolated storage

Tags: c#, video, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage, isolatedstoragefile

I am making a video recording app. the video is recorded and stored in the isolated storage but i want to enable user to transfer his video off the phone... maybe transferring the video to the "Music+Videos" section of the phone or by some other means.

isolated storage video code:

```
// File details for storing the recording.        
    private IsolatedStorageFileStream isoVideoFile;


private void StartVideoRecording()
    {
        try
        {
        videos = null;
        isoVideoFileName = string.Format(dateTime.Day.ToString() + dateTime.Month.ToString() + dateTime.Year.ToString() + "_" + dateTime.Hour.ToString() + dateTime.Minute.ToString() + dateTime.Second.ToString()+".mp4");

            //SAVE TO LOCAL MEMORY............

        videos.Add(isoVideoFileName.ToString());
        IsolatedStorageSettings settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
        if (settings.Contains("Storage"))
        {
            List<string> vids = new List<string>();
            List<string> vids1 = new List<string>();
            vids.AddRange(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["Storage"] as List<string>);
            videos.AddRange(vids);
            settings["Storage"] = videos;
            settings.Save();
        }
        else
        {
            settings["Storage"] = videos;
            settings.Save();
        }
        //.......................................

            if (captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice != null
                && captureSource.State == CaptureState.Started)
            {
                captureSource.Stop();


                fileSink.CaptureSource = captureSource;
                fileSink.IsolatedStorageFileName = isoVideoFileName;
            }

            // Begin recording.
            if (captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice != null
                && captureSource.State == CaptureState.Stopped)
            {
                captureSource.Start();
            }


            disp.Text = "DashCam - Recording...";
            status = "recording";

        }


        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            //{
            //    MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            //    
            //});
        }
    }
```

UPDATE 1

As I was working through this problem, I found the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_VIDEO provided in the documentation which enables us to transfer videos to the camera roll. However the manifest is missing, so is there any other way to make this possible ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Got any results or failed attempts to share? Any specific problems? You haven't actually asked a question at all - and StackOverflow generally expects a specific one, demonstrating understanding and effort made toward a problem.

Comment: sorry about that, kind of new around here, will make it more specific next time... I have tried a lot to get the file off the isolated storage. the question "Is there any means by which the data from isolated storage can be taken off the phone ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look this topic: http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/showthread.php/239630-Can-i-save-video-to-CameraRoll

Also info about Music+Video Hub: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx